# Microsoft Access Text Driver: Querying without extension name in table

Tags: csv, ms-access, odbc

We have ODBC queries to a temporary directory of delimited text files using "Microsoft Access Text Driver (.txt, .csv)" which is driven by the Access Database Engine (v. 16.0.5044.1000) and ODBC connector ACEODBC.DLL (v 16.00.16827.20014) under Windows 11.  Our connection string is as follows:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DBQ=U:\path\to\Temp\directory;Extensions="asc,csv,tab,txt";
```

The connection works, but includes the extension in the pseudo table names which is problematic for our application.  Is there a way to either

1. Instruct the driver to strip the extension, e.g., `SELECT * from table` rather than `SELECT * from table.csv`
2. Use delimited files without an extension so that we can programmatically remove the extensions from the temporary directory files?

I have tried adding `*.` (as well as `*` ) to the extensions list:  Extensions="asc,csv,tab,txt,*." which is an option for Microsoft's SQL server but does not appear to be implemented on the Access database engine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you using connection string? This appears to be something new to me. I have used Access External Data to set links. I have used VBA to establish links. I have used query object to connect to Excel sheet (if this is possible with txt file, I haven't found example). None have extension included in link table name. How could a file (delimited or otherwise) not have an extension?

Comment: Just figured out how to build connection to txt file in query object. Would you be interested in that?

Comment: The connection string is being used with an ODBC interface library (pyODBC).  The main reason I am looking to get rid of the dots is that queries are built automatically based on a drag/drop interface and the current architecture includes the table name in the attribute portion of select as we may be querying multiple tables.  e.g.:  SELECT a.f1, b.f1 FROM a, b.  I haven't tried SELECT a.csv.f1 FROM a.csv yet, but I know that our table/attribute parsing code will break.  As for  the txt file connection, if it follows a generic ODBC query then yes please, but we query other sources as well.

Comment: Might tag for pyODBC, not just ODBC. I use only Access query. Example of SQL connecting to txt file: `SELECT Seq, Unit, Garage
FROM Condos.txt IN 'C:\Users\Owner\June\MyStuff'[Text;DSN=Condos Link Specification1;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=437;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Owner\June\MyStuff];`. Data is read only. But you don't want the `txt` in there so I guess this wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: It appears that you have to use an extension (.txt or .csv) with this driver; but if you do so, you can still give the table an alias and use it that way: `SELECT MyTbl.f1 FROM a.csv as MyTbl`